# Incomplete data or weird characters during serial communication

Tags: linux, serial-port, pyserial, tty, minicom

I am struggling with reading data from the device.
I've searched for this issue with many different keywords, but couldn't find my case.

I am a beginner at serial communication. Thanks in advance for the help and advice from the experts.

## The first issue with minicom (and picocom)

When I send the command (in this case, `M;\r\n`) multiple times, which is from the manual of the device, I expect the output something like `+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.09;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000`.

However, what I received are the incomplete strings and the strings with some weird characters like `��ÚZڂ²Êʢ` in `minicom` or `▒▒▒▒` in `picocom`. I can receive the complete data only few times. The picocom looks more stable but is still not complete.

### OUTPUT

By minicom:

```
Welcome to minicom 2.7.1

OPTIONS: I18n
Compiled on May  6 2018, 08:30:41.
Port /dev/ttyS0, 02:19:52

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys

;;+0000.0ÿÛۃ��kþ;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.12;+20.6;+000;�²ê¢~ꢊ�û+0694.12;+20.6;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.11;+0694.12;+20.6;+000;+000
;ëÿ;+0000.®ÿ»¿▒ÿ¿r��ÚZڂ²Êʢr��ÚZڒ�r²ÚZڂ��ÚZڂ��j¤ø;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.11;+0694.12;+20.6;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.11;+0694.12;+20.6;+000;+000
;;+0000.0»û��û;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.6;+000;+000
;ëÿ;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.6;+000;+000
;ëÿ;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.6;+000;+00;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.6;+000;+000
;ëÿ;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.6;+000;+000
;ëÿ;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.6;+000;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.6;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.6;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.6;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.6;+000;+000
;ë;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
ÿû+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.11;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
;ëÿ;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
;ëÿ;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
ÿû/0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.8;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.8;+000;+000
|;ëÿ;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.8;+000;+000
»ÿ;+0000.0뻫»Ëˣsÿû+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.8;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
;ëÿ;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
»+0694.10;+0694.11;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000
;ëÿ;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.10;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000
ÿû+0694.10;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000
°¹▒¿³ÏϿó��ÚZ�rºÚZڂ��ÚZڂ��j¤ø+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.09;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000
;ëÿ;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.09;+0694.10;+20.7;+000»ÿ;+0000.0;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.09;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.09;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000
»+0694.09;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000
ÊþåÏ9¦▒%&L�7;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.09;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000
;ëÿ;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.09;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.09;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.09;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000
;;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.09;+0694.10;+20.7;+000;+000
```

By picocom:

```
picocom v3.1

port is        : /dev/ttyS0
flowcontrol    : none
baudrate is    : 9600
parity is      : none
databits are   : 8
stopbits are   : 1
escape is      : C-a
local echo is  : no
noinit is      : no
noreset is     : no
hangup is      : no
nolock is      : no
send_cmd is    : sz -vv
receive_cmd is : rz -vv -E
imap is        :
omap is        :
emap is        : crcrlf,delbs,
logfile is     : none
initstring     : none
exit_after is  : not set
exit is        : no

Type [C-a] [C-h] to see available commands
Terminal ready
;▒▒;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.08;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
▒▒▒▒>00;+0694.08;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.08;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.08;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.08;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
▒▒;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.08;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00▒ۣs▒▒▒▒20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
;▒▒;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
▒▒;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
;▒▒;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0000.00;+0694.07;+0694.10;+20.9;+000;+000
```

## The second issue with pyserial

I think the second issue may be related to the first issue. Ultimately I want to read the data from the device and log it by python (`pyserial`). This is the part of my code to read the data.

```py
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS4', baudrate=9600)
ser.write(str.encode('M;\r'))
time.sleep(.2)
data = ser.readline()
data = data.decode("utf-8")
ser.close()
```

This code block runs every N seconds.
Basically, this code works once it received the first data, but need unexpected long delay to receive the first complete data.

In other words, `print(len(data))` always gives `0` before successfully receiving the first data. After waiting for a very long time with zero `len(data)`, it receives the data well at some time (nonzero `len(data)` without any weird characters). Once it successfully received the data, the code continues to work fine without any problems as I want it to.

The problem here is that I have to wait for a very long time to receive a complete data string (even longer than 3 days (!)). Can anybody help me to resolve these issues? Thank you.

Comment: First rule of serial communication is to configure both ends to the same settings.  You only mention how one end is configured.  Why assume the other end is the same?  *"I expect the output ..."* -- *"Output"* is relative to its source; when you neglect to mention the source, the statement becomes ambiguous.  In this case "response" would be a better word choice for the data *received* from this mystery device.  BTW evaluation of *"weird characters"* is simpler by examining the raw data instead of the ASCII translations.  E.G. log the session data, then review the log file in a hex editor.

Comment: @sawdust I appreciate your comment with detailed explanation. I am sorry to have confused you by using the ambiguous word. I am new to serial communication, I have tried to use the appropriate terminology as much as I can, but I haven't been able to. Now I am trying to understand and follow your comment. Reading your comment I feel I have to provide more information, including the setting of the other end (If my understanding is correct, this is the source).

Comment: My first question here is what is "the setting" you are mentioning to? Do you mean the baud rate, parity, and stop bits? If so, I followed the configuration of the device (9600 baud 8 N 1) when I get the response from the device with minicom, picocom, and pyserial.
The second question is how to "log the session data"? If there is any software or command for this, I would appreciate if you could point me to the right way to do this.

Comment: *"Do you mean the baud rate, parity, and stop bits?"* -- Yes, as well as frame (aka character) size and flow-control (hardware or software or none).    **Minicom** has a logging capability, aka "capture".  Did you notice that after **minicom** starts up, it displays the line `Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys`?

Comment: You need to ensure you do not have a hardware issue.  Number one concern is that the ground connection of the serial link is secure, i.e. the 3rd wire besides RxD & TxD (plus optional HW flow control).  Any chance of EMI, e.g. nearby sources of RF)?  Long cable? Crappy cable or connections? Cable is coiled?  Have you tried testing on a different host computer with different cable and another mystery device?

Comment: I really appreciate your comments. From your comment I was able to get valuable and helpful hints mostly regarding the hardware part. There was a non-twisted and non-shielded cable. There was also no ground cable. Potential noise sources may be the RFs from nearby instruments. I have two different sets with the same hardware/software configurations. Let me try to figure it out! Many thanks.